# Can someone explain to me what's the difference between a linked list and a linked bag?

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

Having trouble in finding the difference between a **linked bag** and a **linked list**

Thanks

Comment: Not sure there is a difference. Bag is generally used to indicate an unordered collection. Obviously a linked list can be unordered as well.

Comment: *Linked bag* is a bit of an oxymoron, since a bag is an abstract data type, but the linked part indicates an implementation. Where did you find the term?

Comment: A bag is a multiset; that is, an element can occur more than once. A linked list is a possible choice for the underlying representation in the implementation of bags. The term "linked bag" most likely refers to such an implementation. (There seems to be a bunch of implementations with that name on the internets.)

Comment: @john How can a linked list be unordered?

Comment: @KeithThompson Yes, I was not very clear. I meant it could be processed in manner where the order did not matter. Seems molbdnilo's comment is more useful.

Comment: See [MutiSet (bag) - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type)#Multiset) - essentially instead of adding duplicate nodes -- you increase a "refcount" on the first to indicate the addition of a second identical node. When deleting node, you decrement the recount on removal of that node on each delete until it reaches `0` -- only then is the node actually removed.